# Remove KTX container from ASTC texture

Tags: opengl, textures, astc

Is there an easy way to remove the container from my ASTC 8x8 texture I have in a KTX file. I want to use ARM's astc-encoder tool to go from `.astc` -> `.png` but I only have the KTX file which is in ASTC 8x8 format

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use the KTX SDK[1] to load the container and then save off the contained images as individual ASTC files. More info in the KTX forums[2].

1. https://github.com/KhronosGroup/KTX-Software
2. https://forums.khronos.org/forumdisplay.php/103-KTX-file-format-for-OpenGL-OpenGL-ES-and-WebGL-textures